OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Oracle: ORA-03135: connection lost contact Process ID: 23362 Session ID: 1542 Serial number: 42528
I am getting the following error message while connecting Power BI Desktop from my local machine. DB is also installed on my local machine.


Error Message : OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Oracle: ORA-03135: connection lost contact Process ID: 23362 Session ID: 1542 Serial number: 42528

Wanted to import data to power bi
